# jq capture - how to properly key with captured string

Tags: shell-script, jq

I routinely use `lshw -json` to abstract system data on Linux hosts. In the current scenario, I've extracted network data from lshw via `lshw -c network -json` and have need of extracting, further, data about the NIC on the machine.

To duplicate where I am at:

```
# lshw -c network -json > /var/tmp/network.json
```

Now, I need a JSON structure that encapsulates only the id and logical name of the network interface where the businfo has `pci@` removed from the string. This gets me close:

```
# jq '.[] | {id: .logicalname, bus: .businfo | capture("pci@(?<bus>.*)")}' /var/tmp/network.json
{
  "id": "eth0",
  "bus": {
    "bus": "0000:01:00.0"
  }
}
{
  "id": "eth1",
  "bus": {
    "bus": "0000:01:00.1"
  }
}
{
  "id": "eth2",
  "bus": {
    "bus": "0000:01:00.2"
  }
}
{
  "id": "eth3",
  "bus": {
    "bus": "0000:01:00.3"
  }
}
```

Obviously, the problem is the additionally keyed `bus` to `bus`. I cannot seem to figure out how to get capture to work in such a way as to return the following structure:

```
# jq '.[] | {id: .logicalname, bus: .businfo | capture("pci@(?<bus>.*)")}' /var/tmp/network.json
{
  "id": "eth0",
  "bus": "0000:01:00.0"
}
{
  "id": "eth1",
  "bus": "0000:01:00.1"
}
{
  "id": "eth2",
  "bus": "0000:01:00.2"
}
{
  "id": "eth3",
  "bus": "0000:01:00.3"
}
```

Any jq gurus out there? I find the jq documentation to be mildly lacking for use-cases such as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to achieve this with `capture`, but you could use `sub`:

```
jq '.[] | {id: .logicalname, bus: .businfo | sub("pci@"; "")}' /var/tmp/network.json
```